# cannot parse hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am new to hibernate .. and I am facing some basic problems :

My xml is

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration
    xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</property>
<property name="connection.username">user</property>
<property name="connection.password">user123</property>
<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<mapping class="hibernateDTO.StudentDetails"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have written 2 classes one which is entity class and other with a main method to store / read operations.
I am using hibernate 4 and once I run my class I get exception

```
Nov 13, 2014 10:58:58 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
Nov 13, 2014 10:58:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 13, 2014 10:58:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 13, 2014 10:58:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 13, 2014 10:58:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2165)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2056)
at hibernateTest.Hirbernate.main(Hirbernate.java:20)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 5 of document  : The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
    ... 3 more
```

My jars are

hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final

antlr-2.7.7

dom4j-1.6.1

hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final

hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final

hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final

jandex-1.1.0.Final

javassist-3.18.1-GA

jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA

jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1

jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final

and mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin

am I missing out in jars or have wrong jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the *first* line in all XML file, must be something similar to:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

So, you can try the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">user123</property>
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="hibernateDTO.StudentDetails"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

See also [*XML Validator* online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm) and [*Hibernate Configuration* in **www.tutorialspoint.com**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm)

Comment: Hey, @AndyHayden! -- What? ... Aaaaaah! Ha, ha. I think I was thinking in https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html -- Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your XML processing instruction above your `DOCTYPE` declaration, so to get rid of the XML parsing error, the start of your file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Second problem: you're referencing both a DTD file (for Hibernate version 3) and an XML schema (for version 4). You should probably get rid of the `DOCTYPE` declaration altogether.

Comment: You still get an error about an invalid XML processing instruction error on the same line? Sounds like your file wasn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

do it like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

        <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
```

the problem you have done is you  have again defined namespaced in `hibernate-configuration` tag.

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration
    xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<session-factory>
```

Comment: yes you are right i have typed wrong. thanks for informing. I am editing it.